# Move constructor disappears in derived class when adding custom destructor

Tags: c++, inheritance, destructor, move-semantics

I have a move-only Base class and a Derived which inherits Base's constructors. I would like to give a Derived a custom destructor, but when I do so it no longer inherits Base's move constructor. Very mysterious. What is happening?

[godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/q3DuHL)

```
// move-only
struct Base {
    Base() = default;
    Base(Base const &) = delete;
    Base(Base &&) {}
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    using Base::Base;

    // remove this and it all works
    ~Derived() { /* ... */ }
};

int main() {
    Base b;
    // works
    Base b2 = std::move(b);

    Derived d;
    // fails
    Derived d2 = std::move(d);
}
```

Comment: Maybe give `Derived` a move constructor anyway?  If Derived has any data members then the the base move constructor will be incorrect

Comment: Your base class has no virtual destructor. Not sure if that is the problem, but it seems suspicious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The move constructor is not inherited with `using Base::Base;` in the way that you seem to think it is, because the move constructor in `Base` does not have the signature that a move constructor in `Derived` would have. The former takes a `Base&&`, the latter a `Derived&&`.

Then in `Derived` you are declaring a destructor. This inhibits the implicit declaration of a move constructor for `Derived`. So there is no move constructor in `Derived`.

The compiler then falls back to `Derived`'s implicitly generated copy constructor for `Derived d2 = std::move(d);`. But that is defined as deleted because the base class of `Derived` is not copy-able. (You manually deleted `Base`s copy constructor.)

In overload resolution the deleted copy constructor is chosen over the Base classes inherited `Base(Base&&)` constructor (although a `Derived` rvalue could bind to `Base&&`), because the latter requires a conversion sequence that is not considered *exact match*, while binding to a `const Derived&` is considered *exact match* for the purpose of overload resolution.

Also there is the proposed wording for the resolution of [CWG issue 2356](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2356) which would exclude the inherited `Base` move constructor from participating in overload resolution at all. (From what I can tell this is what the compiler are implementing already.)

If you don't have a good reason to declare a destructor, don't do so. If you do have a reason, then you need to default the move operations again, as you did for the move constructor in `Base`. (You probably want to default the move assignment operator as well if the classes are supposed to be assignable.)

If you intend to use the class hierarchy polymorphically, you should declare a virtual (defaulted) destructor in the polymorphic base, but you do not need to declare a destructor in the derived classes.

Comment: `Derived&&` can be implicitly converted to `Base&&` though, so it doesn't seem to be explained yet why `Derived d2 = std::move(d)` can't execute `B(B&&)`.  The error message seems to suggest that overload resolution is choosing `D(D const&) = delete;` over `B(B&&)`

Comment: @M.M Because that is a worse match for overload resolution. It requires a conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Move constructors are generated under specific circumstances.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_member_functions

In creating a destructor, you have stopped the generation of a move constructor by the compiler.

Also, create a virtual Base destructor if you don't have one. Default it if it doesn't have to do anything special. Same with your Base move constructor, just don't leave it empty, declare it default. You're using `=delete`, use `=default` as well.

Answer (score 1):

The inherited move constructor does not have the signature for the derived class.

In the first case without the explicitly declared destructor the compiler implicitly declares the default move constructor for the derived class.

In the second case when the destructor is explicitly declared the move constructor is not implicitly declared by the compiler.

From the C++ 17 Standard (15.8.1 Copy/move constructors)

> 8 If the deﬁnition of a class X does not explicitly declare a move
>   constructor, a non-explicit one will be implicitly declared as
>   defaulted if and only if
>
> (8.1) X does not have a user-declared copy constructor,
>
> (8.2) X does not have a user-declared copy assignment operator,
>
> —(8.3) X does not have a user-declared move assignment operator, and
>
> **> —(8.4) X does not have a user-declared destructor.**

But in any case the ,move constructor of the base class is not the move constructor of the derived class due to different signatures.